# Install Mint from Windows 7 without cd/pen drive

Tags: linux, windows, installation, linux-mint

I have prepared partition, Mint iso and Windows 7. Can I easily install Mint directly from Windows without using pen drive or CD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not do that. You create another partition and put a Linux live image there. Then you boot this system and install Linux Mint like you would from CD or USB

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have many issues.

During the install on Mint, you will be allowed to select install options.  If Mint detects a preexisting OS, it defaults to "install along side OS xxx."

I believe from there you can select your partition or create new ones.